# Sharing list between functions

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I recently asked another question asking how to pass a list from one function to another, which was kindly answered by @Modred. Essentially what I've got now is this:

```
def run_command():
    machines_off = []
        # Some stuff .....
        machines_off.append(machineName)
        # Some stuff ....
    wol_machines(machines_off)

def wol_machines(machines_off):
    # Some stuff ....
```

(I've cleared off all the non-essential code for this example as it's 300+ lines).

Now, each function is called by clicking on a tkinter button; the run_command is always run and sometimes will add items to the list 'machines_off'. I only want it to action machines_off if the second function button is clicked. At the moment after clicking on the run_command button, it runs through the whole script, including the second function when I don't want it to. I assume as I'm forwarding the list onto the second function (with the 5th line), it's bypassing the need to click the second functions button.

What do I need to change/add to allow the list from the first function to be available to the second, but not action it until needed??

Many thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your code looks something like:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button

def run_command():
    machines_off = []
    # Some stuff .....
    machineName = "foo"
    machines_off.append(machineName)
    # Some stuff ....
    wol_machines(machines_off)

def wol_machines(machines_off):
    print "wol_machines was called"
    print "contents of machines_off: ", machines_off
    # Some stuff ....

root = Tk()
a = Button(text="do the first thing", command=run_command)
b = Button(text="do the second thing", command=wol_machines)
a.pack()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you want the functions to execute independently of one another, you shouldn't call `wol_machines` from within `run_command`. You'll have to find some other way for both functions to see the list. One way of doing this is to use a global value.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button

machines_off = []

def run_command():
    #reset machines_off to the empty list.
    #delete these next two lines if you want to retain old values.
    global machines_off
    machines_off = []
    # Some stuff .....
    machineName = "foo"
    machines_off.append(machineName)
    # Some stuff ....

def wol_machines():
    print "wol_machines was called"
    print "contents of machines_off: ", machines_off
    # Some stuff ....

root = Tk()
a = Button(text="do the first thing", command=run_command)
b = Button(text="do the second thing", command=wol_machines)
a.pack()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is the simplest change to your original code that can give you your desired behavior, but global values are generally considered a sign of bad design. A more object oriented approach could localize the global into a class attribute.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.machines_off = []
        a = Button(self, text="do the first thing", command=self.run_command)
        b = Button(self, text="do the second thing", command=self.wol_machines)
        a.pack()
        b.pack()
    def run_command(self):
        #reset machines_off to the empty list.
        #delete this next line if you want to retain old values.
        self.machines_off = []
        # Some stuff .....
        machineName = "foo"
        self.machines_off.append(machineName)
        # Some stuff ....

    def wol_machines(self):
        print "wol_machines was called"
        print "contents of machines_off: ", self.machines_off
        # Some stuff ....

root = App()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you're a superstar! That's exactly what I need.
I've gone with the first option as it's the simplest to understand.
One question though, why don't I need another 'global machines_off' line in the second function?